# Simple Issue with PHP While Loop

Tags: php, sql, loops, while-loop

I have this

```
mysqli_select_db($connect,"users");

$response = "Select * from revbut where onuser='$u'";
$rquery  =  mysqli_query($connect,$response);
$norows = mysqli_num_rows($rquery);






while($responseanswer=mysqli_fetch_array($rquery)){


if(json_encode($responseanswer['response']=='approve'))
{
include('response-2.php');  
}

else if(json_encode($responseanswer['response']=='reject'))
{
    include('response-3.php');
}
else
{
echo "Nothing in here. ";   
}
}
```

in database, there are two fields. So one is approve, whereas the other is reject. But the php is including the response-2.php file twice. why so?

Comment: please tell me the json_encode what is doing there ? I mean inside the if it alway return value

Answer (score 3):

Because you are comparing $responseanswer['response'] with 'approve' and with 'reject', and then json_encoding() the true or false. The json encoding will be a string such as "true" or "false", and if("true") and if("false") in PHP are both true. In fact, the only strings that will if() to false are the strings "0" and "". It even specifically mentions if("false") here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

It's not clear why the json_encoding() is needed at all, because you haven't given any sample data, but I'm pretty sure that's the bug.

Comment: oh..without json_encode..the thing just won't work...it would display $reposneanswer['serial'] and everything else...but not ['response'];

Comment: well, you need to capture the result of json_encode() into a variable. In the code you presented, the result of the encoding is being thrown away.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're running the loop for every record in your result set.  Your loop basically says include response-2.php every time the 'response' field equals "approve".  If you have 5 records in the table where the 'response' field is "approve", your loop will include response-2.php 5 times.

Before your while loop, you could establish an iteration variable:

$i = 1;

At the end of your loop, iterate the value by one:

$i++;

Then, check the value of $i.  If it equals anything greater than 1, don't do the include again.  For example:

```
$i = 1;
while($responseanswer=mysqli_fetch_array($rquery)){


if(json_encode($responseanswer['response']=='approve'))
{
($i == 1 ? include('response-2.php') : "");  
}

else if(json_encode($responseanswer['response']=='reject'))
{
($i == 1 ? include('response-3.php') : "");  
}
else
{
echo "Nothing in here. ";   
}
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I don't have email notifications turned on. I've provided a sample.  I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  You have may have to translate this to a more traditional if/else syntax if you need to do additional procedures when the iteration value is greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must do this in you database and you should do this:

have one record that hase key column and value the key name is for example

**rejectOrAprove** and the value if its aprove be 1 and if reject be 0.